# Devextreme Data grid

Tags: c#, reactjs, entity-framework-core, devextreme

I have class interview :

```
Class Interview {
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public Guid Id { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
```

}
And Class Answer:

```
Class Answer{
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public Guid Id { get; set; }
public Guid QuestionId { get; set; }
public string AnswerText { get; set; }
}
```

At Frontend I have web page contains data grid using devextreme:
[image: DataGrid]
I need to apply search filter, sort and group on Server Side api. I applied filter using DataSourceLoadOptions but can't apply sort and group.
I need your help at this point "apply sorting and grouping on Server Side"

Comment: Show you LINQ query. How do you fill grid?

Comment: IQueryable<Interview> source = _appContext.Interviews
                .Include(x => x.Task)
                .Include(x => x.Answers.OrderBy(p => p.AnswerText))
                .Where(c => c.SurveyId == surveyId && c.isDeleted == false);

Comment: Update question, not comments.